# passing lambda function as an argument of HOF

Tags: haskell

I have a function like this

```
f d = foldl (\acc x -> acc ++ [distance] where distance = 1) d [1..3]
```

For some GHCI says:

```
error: parse error on input ‘where’
```

Comment: you can rewrite this as `f d = d ++ (replicate 3 1)`.  Perhaps you wanted to express something else?

Comment: @karakfa I put 1 for simplicity, consider this e ^ x - 2016

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`where` clauses apply to declaration groups, not to expressions. You use `let` instead:

```
(\acc x -> let distance = 1 in acc ++ [distance])
```